# Get aggregates (average, median, max, ...) by multiple criteria

Tags: r, aggregation, plyr

I have a dataframe in this form

```
    salary crit1  crit2  crit3
1   41000  TRUE   TRUE   ...
2   50000  TRUE   FALSE  ...
3   39500  FALSE  FALSE
4   40500  TRUE   FALSE
5   75000  FALSE  FALSE
```

Now I would like to use some R script to calculate aggregates by the criteria crit1, crit2, crit3 ... So I want the aggregates to include those rows where each criterion is TRUE, e.g. average/median/max over all rows where is crit1 TRUE, average/median/max over all rows where crit2 is TRUE, etc. I am **NOT** interested in combinations of the criteria.

Somewhat like this

```
        crit1      crit2     crit3
average 43833.33  40250      ...
median  40500     40250
max     50000     41000
```

Based on related posts and web pages that I found, it seemed that maybe [ddply from the plyr package](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/) could help, but could not figure out yet how to avoid that I get aggregates by the **combinations** of the criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a minimal reproducible example:

```
#set up some data
set.seed=129
sdt <- data.frame( sal=round(rgamma(10,5,1/8000),-2),
                 crit1=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10,replace=TRUE),
                 crit2=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10,replace=TRUE))
```

So now:

```
byl <- function(ind,x) summary(x[ind])
sapply(sdt[,-1],byl,sdt[,1])
```

does what you seems to be asking for.

Answer (score -2):

Another approach is using aggregate function. For example:

```
aggregate(salary~crit1+crit2+crit3, DatasetName, mean)
```

produces mean salary by all three criteria

you can replace the mean with other statistics.

Comment: This is not answering, what has been asked in the question. You may want to update accordingly _(Not my down vote)_